# Process Thymeleaf attributes multiple times

Tags: spring-mvc, template-engine, thymeleaf

I would like to be able to store HTML with Thymeleaf attributes as Strings in a database. I am able to store HTML without Thymeleaf attributes already:

**Method in controller class**

```
// this method would actually get String from database first
@ModelAttribute("someCode")
public String populateSomeCode() {
    return "This is <h1>some code</h1>";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
...
  <body>
    <div th:utext="${someCode}">HTML will go here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This would produce the desired result of displaying an H1 saying "This is some code".

I am wondering if it is possible to include Thymeleaf attributes in the String and then have those attributes processed. If I changed the String to be:

```
"This is <h1 th:text=\"'another String'\">some code</h1>"
```

I would like the result to be an H1 saying "This is another String", but currently it would still say "This is some code". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use Thymeleaf `__${expression}__` preprocessor feature?

Like this:

```
"This is __<h1 th:text=\"'another String'\"> some code</h1>__"
```

Comment: The preprocessor feature is what I needed. Thank you!